# Resolvent is a bounded operator?

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to prove that for a bounded operator $T$ the resolvent $R(z,T) = (T - zI)^{-1}$ is an analytic function of $z \in \mathbb{C}$ (for $z$ in the resolvent set). The first step is to use the resolvent identity
$$\frac{R(z + \Delta z,T) -  R(z,T)}{\Delta z} =  \, R(z + \Delta z,T)R(z,T) $$
There are some things I am unsure of. If we let $\Delta z \to 0$ then how does one show that $R(z + \Delta z,T) \to R(z,T)$ (in operator norm)? One could use the above resolvent identity if one assumes that $R(z,T)$ is a bounded operator in some small neighbourhood of $z$. However unless $|z| > \| T \|$ I'm not sure how to show boundedness.

Answer (score 1):

You can expand the resolvent $(T-zI)^{-1}$ about any $z_0$ where the resolvent exists:
\begin{align}
     (T-zI)^{-1} & =((T-z_0I)-(z-z_0)I)^{-1} \\
    & = ((T-z_0)(I-(z-z_0)(T-z_0 I)^{-1})^{-1} \\
    & = (I-(z-z_0)(T-z_0 I)^{-1})^{-1}(T-z_0)^{-1} \\
    & = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(z-z_0)^{n}(T-z_0 I)^{-(n+1)}.
\end{align}
This series converges absolutely and uniformly for all $z$ for which
$$
                 |z-z_0|\|(T-z_0 I)^{-1}\| < 1.
$$
The resulting series is holomorphic in $z$ as an operator function of $z$.

Comment: This begs the question since what I am asking is if $\| (T - z_0 I)^{-1} \| $ is finite

Comment: @UtilityMaximiser : By the definition of the resolvent, $T-z_0I$ has a bounded everywhere defined inverse in order for $z_0$ to be in the resolvent set.

Comment: After thinking about it a bit more, isn't this issue resolved by the Open Mapping Theorem? i.e. we have a continuous linear operator $T-z_0 I$ and we want to show its inverse (assuming it exists) is also continuous. Isn't this then equivalent to requiring that $T-z_0 I$ is an open map?

Comment: @UtilityMaximiser : $T$ has a closed graph. So $T-z_0$ has a closed graph. If $T-z_0$ is surjective and injective, then $(T-z_0)^{-1}$ exists and has a closed graph, which guarantees that $(T-z_0)^{-1}$ is ontinuous.